# Tears in chrome after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: display, chromium, 16.04, tearing

I recently updated Ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 and right after, I started noticing tears in viewing webpages in chromium (and nowhere else).

I tried googling the problem but couldn't find anything.

The problem stays even after rebooting.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like ticking the `Use hardware acceleration when available` option in the advanced settings in chromium fixed this problem.

I still don't know why it started only after upgrading to 16.04 though.